# Scraping Domino's Promo Page using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to **scrape** the promo page of Domino's Pizza Canada. Essentially I want the name and price of the promo. I am unable to get a result with my code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dom_mainp = "https://www.dominos.ca/"
response = requests.get(dom_mainp)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

soup.find("span", {"class": "promo__title__emphasis"})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because promo code and price is not available on your url target https://www.dominos.ca

Comment: Replace your url with this url https://m.dominos.co.in/offers and then try to scrap

Comment: I inspected the element, there is price and title. For instance: 
<h2 class="promo__title">Unlimited Medium <span class="promo__title__emphasis">2-Topping<br>Pizzas</span></h2>

Comment: If you look at the page source, you won't find the content. It's generated by javascript. So you need to access that after the page is rendered. Try using selenium to open the page and allow it to render, then you you can use the code to find your html elements

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Selenium will allow you to grab the page's HTML after the script loads all the elements. However, for this particular page, the soup was not yielding any `span` elements even after I loaded the page with selenium. It turns out it took a few seconds for my pc to properly load the script/elements so I had to put in a sleep function to wait for the page to load.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.dominos.ca/"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # wait ten seconds for all elements to load
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')
spans = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "promo__title__emphasis"})
print(spans)
```

Returns:

```
[<span class="promo__title__emphasis">2-Topping<br/>Pizzas</span>, <span class="promo__title__emphasis">2-Topping<br/>Pizzas</span>]
```